# Can one make a Macbook behave like a USB-Drive

Tags: macos, usb, hosts, emulation

Is there a Way to emulate an usb-drive with a Macbook? I do not mean to emulate usb drives on my macbook!
I would like to plug a double usb cable to my macbook and e.g. my TV. I want the TV to think that my macbook is an usb-drive and record/timeshift directly to my mac.

Comment: No. Get a TV with FireWire.

Comment: Look at software such as Xbox Media Center (http://xbmc.org/). Don't let the name fool you, it can run on osx.

Answer (score 3):

If your TV can see samba shares then use File Sharing module. I've assumed you're using Mountain Lion, but I think the directions are still the same.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click on Sharing module
3. Add a shared folder to the USB drive attached to the MacBook
4. Add the users (warning: these permissions are for all folders not just the current one highlighted)
5. Click the Options button
6. Check Share files and folders using SMB (Windows)
7. Select the OSX User you want to link to the SMB account
8. You'll be prompted to specify a password (warning: I believe this flavour of Samba will send passwords in clear text)
9. Find the Samba share on your TV, specify the username and credentials from the MacBook you've just linked to Samba sharing.

Answer (score 1):

No.

While there is [Target Disk Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_Disk_Mode), it is Thunderbolt/Firewire only, and then usually only exposes a HFS+ formatted volume (which is pretty much Mac only) with your data on it.